# How to reference more than one bean from JNDI in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have configured a mail session on JBoss EAP 6.1. I am using Spring 4. I am using a lookup like this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="contactMailSession"
                 jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Contact"
                 expected-type="javax.mail.Session" />
```

What if I added three more mail sessions on the JBoss server and added three more lookups in the Spring XML configuration file? How would I inject one bean over another? I can't add a qualifier to the `<jee:jndi-lookup ... />` tag.

The question is: What if I had this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="contactMailSession"
                 jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Contact"
                 expected-type="javax.mail.Session" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="signupMailSession"
                 jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/SignUp"
                 expected-type="javax.mail.Session" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="userMailSession"
                 jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/User"
                 expected-type="javax.mail.Session" />
```

How would I autowire these?

Comment: You can look up spring bean profiling if you want to add dependencies based on different profiles. This might not answer your question but just for info. Also, wouldn't this be the same case if it were 3 different Strings? You would refer them through the id correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to add a `@Qualifier` to the field that is being autowired - setting the value to the `id` of the `Session` that was looked up in JNDI. For example:

```
public class BeanThatNeedsContactMailSession {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("contactMailSession")
    private Session mailSession;

}
```

And

```
public class BeanThatNeedsSignupMailSession {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("signupMailSession")
    private Session mailSession;

}
```

Etc.